# Is there a way to assign keys in the command pallet list to jump to desired item instead of the default item in sublime text?

Tags: sublime-text-2

In the command pallet, when I type "gl", the default option is "Git: log", but I would rather have it "Git: Graph All".

For example, I type in "gl" and instead of the default option "Git: Log All", I want it to be "Git: Graph All"

[image]

Is there a way to be able to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out which command corrosponds to which command pallet list items in sublime text?](http://superuser.com/questions/814179/how-to-find-out-which-command-corrosponds-to-which-command-pallet-list-items-in)

Comment: @sww1235 I don't understand how? Here I'm asking whether (and if so how) it's possible to go directly to "Git: Graph All" **from the command pallet itself**. That other question is about the command so it can be assigned as a keyboard shortcut, **without the use of command pallet altogether**. But if there's any relation in the two questions that I'm not seeing, please let me know by elaborating..

Comment: It was marked as a possible duplicate, not a duplicate. The questions seemed extremely similar, and might have been better to make a multipart question