# How to find out which command corrosponds to which command pallet list items in sublime text?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2

The git plugin for sublime text has many options populated in the command pallet

but I want to assign keyboard shortcuts to some of them. How do I find out which commands to use for those commands?

For ex, what command do I use if I want to assign a keyboard shortcut to "Git: Graph All" command?

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+l"], "command": "?? Git: Graph All ??" },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to do this within Sublime. You can look at the source code, though. There will be a file with the ".sublime-commands" extension, in which you can find this information. For the Git plugin:

https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/blob/master/Default.sublime-commands